# Trying to add email contacts to Sendgrid

Tags: ios, swift, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Problem: How can I add an email to a Sendgrid contact list in Swift?

Here's what I've done so far (this is not working)

```
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: sendGridURL)!)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"

let json = [
    "listIds": ["a7aab3b0-0307-40e6-aa6f-7a3964b8fa1f", "0464f62d-9bb7-440c-8f64-ff2b66ec199b"],
    "contacts": [[ "email" : "\(email)" ]]
];

//Headers
request.addValue("Bearer \(sendGridAPIKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
    request.httpBody = data
} catch {
    print("sendgrid \(error)")
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else { print("sendgrid \(error!.localizedDescription)"); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("sendgrid Empty data"); return }

    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("sendgrid \(str)")
    }
}.resume()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using POST not PUT. Now, I'm having the issue where I cannot add contacts to a specific list.